# How can I make node.js automatically load config files?

Tags: configuration, node.js

In my mac os x computer, node.js, you can use 'require()' to load your configuration files, but I am tired of having to do that on all my programs. Is there a way to make node.js automatically load config files?
I tried to put this in my .bash_profile:

```
alias node='node var config = require("./config")'
```

When I enter the node command, it does load the file, but it exits the node shell. Is there a way to do this without making it exiting the node shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-r` switch instead.

e.g `node -r ./config.js`

It will preload that module, and keep the shell for you.